# Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'int'

Tags: python-2.7

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tyler/Desktop/PycharmProjects/Arcade Game/AttackDirectory.py", line 63, in <module>
  ThiefPdmg = randint(lambda x: (round(x*0.75)), lambda x: (round(x*1.00)))(Thief['stats']['Attack'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 242, in randint
  return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'int'
```

I'm still learning python and I'm working on a battle system for a game. I'm sure the code is crude so if you have any way to make it less crude and possibly work better, I'm open to suggestions.

```
import random
import pygame
from random import randint
pygame.init()

Thief = {'name' : 'Thief',
         'Class' : 'Player',
         'Sub-Class' : 'Thief',
         'lvl' : 1,
         'xp' : 0,
         'lvlNext' : 25,
         'Weak' : {'Lightning'},
         'Normal' : {'Shock'
                     'Burn'
                     'Water'
                     'Freeze'},
         'Resistance' : {'Ice'
                         'Fire'},
          'Null' : {'Poison'},
    'stats': {'Attack' : 6,
              'Magic' : 6,
              'Speed' : 5,
              'HP' : 20,
              'MP' : 40}}

def ThiefLevelUp():
    while Thief['lvl'] < 50 and Thief['xp'] >= Thief['lvlNext'] :
        Thief['lvl']+= 1
        xp = Thief['xp'] - Thief['lvlNext']
        lvlNext = round(Thief['lvlNext'] * 1.5)
        Thief['stats']['HP'] = Thief['stats']['HP'] + round(Thief['stats']['HP'] * .25)


    print("Level Up!")
    print('Level:', Thief['lvl'])
    if Thief['xp'] < Thief['lvlNext']:
        print('XP Needed:', Thief['xpNeeded'])
    print('Exp:', Thief['xp'])
    print('Strength:', Thief['stats']['PStrength'])
    print('Prosperity:', Thief['stats']['PProsperity'])
    print('Dexterity:', Thief['stats']['PDexterity'])
    print('Vitality:', Thief['stats']['PVitality'])
    print('Agility:', Thief['stats'][''])

Imp = {'name' : 'Imp',
    'Class' : 'Enemy',
    'lvl' : 1,
    'xp' : 0,
    'lvlNext' : 25,
    'Weak' : {'Lightning'},
    'Normal' : {'Fire',
                'Ice',
                'Poison',
                'Freeze',
                'Burn'},
    'Resistance' : {},
    'Null' : {},
    'stats' : {'Attack' : 8,
               'Speed' : 5,
               'HP' : 25,
               'MP' : 40}}

   ThiefPdmg = randint(lambda x: (round(x*0.75)), lambda x: (round(x*1.00)))(Thief['stats']['Attack'])

  ThiefMdmg = randint(lambda x: (round(x*0.75)), lambda x: (round(x*1.00)))(Thief['stats']['Magic'])

ThiefHP = Thief['stats']['HP']

ImpDMG = randint(lambda x: (round(x*0.75 / Thief['lvl'] + 1, lambda x: (round(x*0.75 / Thief['lvl'] + 1)) )))(Imp['stats']['Attack'])

ImpHP = Imp['stats']['HP']


def AtkMiss():
      if random.random > .25:
    Attack()

else:
    print("You Missed!")
    if random.random > .25:
        ThiefHP - ImpDMG
        ThiefHP = Thief['stats']['HP'] - ImpDMG

def Attack():

    AttackerDMG = ThiefPdmg



    print('You Attacked!')

 if Thief['stats']['Speed'] >= Imp['stats']['Speed']:

ImpHP - ThiefPdmg
ImpHP = Imp['stats']['HP'] - ThiefPdmg

if random.random > .25:
    ThiefHP - ImpDMG
    ThiefHP = Thief['stats']['HP'] - ImpDMG



if Imp['stats']['Speed'] > Thief['stats']['Speed'] :

    ThiefHP - ImpDMG
    print('Thief Took {} Damage!'.format(ImpDMG))

    if random.random > .25:
        ImpHP - ThiefPdmg
        print('Imp Took {} Damage!'.format(ThiefPdmg))

    else:
        print('The Attack Missed!')


if ImpHP <= 0:
     print('{} Was Killed!'.format(Imp['name']))

if ThiefHP <= 0:
    print('You Were Killed!')


def command():

     cmd = raw_input('What Will You Do?')

if 'Atk' in cmd:
    AtkMiss()

else:
    Pass

def Battle():

    Attackerhp = Thief['stats']['HP']

    Defenderhp = Imp['stats']['HP']

    print('An imp appeared!')
    print('                ')
    while Defenderhp and Attackerhp > 0:
         command()
         print('Your Health: {}'.format(ThiefHP))
         print('Enemies Health: {}'.format(ImpHP))

    if Defenderhp <= Defenderhp:
         print('Took {} Damage!'.format(Enemy['name'], Dmg or Mdmg))
```

Where is the error coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `randint` [1] function expects for `int` numbers to be passed as its arguments. Instead, you are passing lambda functions which appear to be unnecessary. Instead of `randint(lambda x: round(x*0.25), lambda x: round(x*0.75))`, for example, just do `randint(round(x*0.25), round(x*0.75))`. Only use lambda where something expects a `function` to be passed to it, like a callback.

1. https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint

Comment: If it works for you, please mark the answer. Cheers.

Comment: Okay, I'll check it in the morning, if it works I'll tell ya and I'll mark the answer

Comment: It fixed the first error, but it says that x isn't defined

Comment: True, because in the context of the lambda, "x" was whatever value was being passed in. Since there's no more lambda, "x" means nothing. Just rethink how you're using `randint`. If you want something between 0 and 100, say, then you would use `randint(0, 100)`...